# Autofac. Naming resolving and child dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Does the named/keyed resolving also resolve child dependencies using a name? Or named resolving applies Name/Key only for resolved type without its child dependencies?

Error occurs:

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program+MainClassOne' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'INamed named' of constructor 'Void .ctor(INamed)'.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.RegisterType<NamedB>().Named<INamed>("B");
        container.RegisterType<NamedA>().Named<INamed>("A");
        container.RegisterType<MainClassOne>().Named<MainClassOne>("A");
        container.RegisterType<MainClassTwo>().Named<MainClassTwo>("B");

        var di = container.Build();
        var a = di.ResolveNamed<MainClassTwo>("B");
        var a2 = di.ResolveNamed<MainClassOne>("A");

    }

    public class MainClassOne
    {
        public MainClassOne(INamed named)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MainClassOne= " + named.Name);
        }
    }

    public class MainClassTwo
    {
        public MainClassTwo(INamed named)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MainClassTwo= " + named.Name);
        }
    }

    public interface INamed
    {
       string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class NamedA : INamed
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return "A"; }
            set { }
        }
    }

    public class NamedB : INamed
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return "B"; }
            set { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's sad, but it seems that only for resolved type. I check "WithParameter" and its working only for specific class. I think its autofac policity. Although they could make a parameter for spreading to children dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is only used when resolving the requested service. If the key was passed to subsequent resolve operations it would require all services in the dependency graph to also be registered with the same key.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using lambda based registrations that make the dependencies for your main classes explicit.

```
container.RegisterType<NamedA>().Named<INamed>("A");    
container.RegisterType<NamedB>().Named<INamed>("B");
container.Register(c => new MainClassOne(c.ResolveNamed<INamed>("A"))).Named<MainClassOne>("A");
container.Register(c => new MainClassTwo(c.ResolveNamed<INamed>("B"))).Named<MainClassTwo>("B");
```

This will allow you to resolve the main classes using their name while ensuring that they also receive the correct named dependency.

Comment: It would be good to have a parameter for regulating the propagation. For my specific case, I solved my problem by setting it inside LifeTimeScope. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. What is the reason for naming MainClassOne and MainClassTwo? `.Named<MainClassOne>("A")`. Is it necessary or have you simply chosen to use the same name for something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Update your registration to look like this:

```
        container.RegisterType<NamedB>().Named<INamed>("B");
        container.RegisterType<NamedA>().Named<INamed>("A");

        container.RegisterType<MainClassOne>()
            .Named<MainClassOne>("A")
            .WithParameter(
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (pi, ctx) => pi.Name == "named",
                    (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<INamed>("A")));

        container.RegisterType<MainClassTwo>()
            .Named<MainClassTwo>("B")
            .WithParameter(
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (pi, ctx) => pi.Name == "named",
                    (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<INamed>("B")));
```

There are probably ways to make this look neater (extension methods etc). Also, consider using Keyed rather than Named parameters.

The "ResolvedParameter" class takes two delegates - the first is a selector, and allows you to determine whether or not the referenced constructor parameter is relevant, and if it is, the second delegate is executed to provide a value.

Take a look at [keyed services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) and [select by context](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) for further information.